# Android Overlay doesn't dispatch events

Tags: android, overlay, touch-event

So i wrote an Overlay with the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` Flag, everything seems to work as it should with the Problem that i want to align the Elements inside the Overlay on bottom of the Screen.
I did this via `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.
Now the Problem is that every touch event inside the Layout gets dispatched to me, while i only want the touches which hit my Controls. I tried calling  `return super.onTouchEvent(event);`  with no succes. Is there any way to return the touch events back to Android so they get handled properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Problem via the Interactive Overlay example, if you got the same or a similar problem the example might help you. http://www.jawsware.mobi/code_OverlayView/